# Removing the plate from an old 1950's schlage door knob

Tags: removal, doorknob

Somehow, I think this door knob would be easier to reassemble if the knob and plate (especially the plate) were removed.  Anyone know how to remove the knob?

I don't even really see a lever or pilot hole.  The one spot near the collar, I think could be some sort of weld.

[image: The other side isn't a knob, but one of those old fashioned levers and handles.]

[image]

Comment: One conclusion.  The lever that I thought was a weld, is in fact a lever and pushes in.  I can get the collar to move slightly, but no progress with the knob otherwise.  Next, I'm wondering if there's a hidden cover plate on the door knob.

Comment: **How is the plate interfering with installing the door knob ?**  Presumably it was designed to be installed intact the way it is. The knob part would have to come off in order to get the plate off. On some doorknobs the knob part has a little push pin you push in to release the knob from the stem.

Comment: The screw at the bottom, along with reinstalling the retaining clip.  Wouldn't cooperate.  There was no room to use the screwdriver as I barely got it off with a small L-driver.  I actually solved this problem as there was a detent on the knob.  The current (new) trick is getting the lock to work at all.  Part of the problem (as I've posted about this on here before).  I had no intention reusing this knob after painting the door.  It's nearing 70 years old.  Couldn't find a knob and lock to fit this particular door.

Comment: Is the hole in your old door to small for modern door knobs ?  If so there are many questions on here that give detailed answers as to how to enlarge the hole.

Comment: This one is more oblique shaped.  There is really no practical way to adjust it for a round knob.  I am looking around the site for other peoples similar problems and solutions.  It seems more common than I would've thought.  Thanks